# How do I modify MacOS system 'Floating' screensaver to show more images at a time?

Tags: macos, root, file-permissions, macos-mojave, screensaver

Anybody out there have experience modifying the existing screensavers on MacOS? I'm running the newest Mojave. I'm hoping to modify the 'Floating' screensaver so it shows more images (i.e. it's 'denser' if you will).

Part of the issue is that I'm not able to modify some of the plists that I was thinking I'd hack around in... I've enabled 'root' but when I try to modify, for example, /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/Styles/Floating.mrbStyle/Contents/Resources/StyleDescription.plist, I'm getting 'not permitted' messages. Won't even let me chmod the file or folder above...

(Yeah, basically I'm trying to hack my way around using Unix experience that's probably 25 years out-of-date :))

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: Ah okay, SIP sorted. Still... could use some help figuring out what needs to be modified to get the effect I'm looking for. (i.e. if someone's bored...)